# Holomorphic map from Annulus $A$ to $\Bbb{C}$ injective on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering if, given an holomorphic map $$h(z) : A \to \Bbb{C}$$ where $A:=\{ z \in \Bbb{C} \mid 1/2 \leq |z| \leq 2\}$ (holomorphic on the interior, can be continuously extended to the boundary) such that it is injective when restricted to $\partial A$, one could conclude that $h$ is injective on $A$.

I tried using the argument principle similar to the case of a disk but wasn't able to conclude much...

Comment: Can you maybe include what you got so far?

Comment: not much honestly :) I fear this is either a one line argument or easily disproved with a counterexample. the same result is true for disks, but there you can use the argument principle. I don't think argument principle is applicable here due to the fact we don't have a holomorphic function on the interior of either of the two boundary curves

Comment: show first that if the image is another annulus, then the two must be holomorphically isomorphic (ratio of radiuses same) and this map is such an isomorphism; this follows using $\log |f|-c\log r$ for appropriate $c$; then the hypotheisis implies that the image is bounded by two Jordan curves by the open mapping theorem, so is isomorphic with an annulus by the extension of RMT, so apply part 1 to conclude

Comment: @Conrad thanks! let me see if I understand that properly: I know that the image of my map is an annulus. 1) you claim this annulus is holomorphically isomorphic to $A$. To prove 1) you suggest to consider $\log |f| - c \log r$. I'm not sure what should I observe with this map. What is $r$? is it $|z|$?

Comment: If the image is an annulus of some radiuses $r_1, r_2$ one can use an analytic isomorphism $\phi$ to move it to $1/2 < |z| < R$ st the map $f=\phi \circ h$ preserves the circle $1/2$ and maps the circle $2$ to $R$; then $\log (2|f|)-c\log (2|z|)$ is obviously harmonic and zero on $|z|=1/2$ and one finds a unique $c$ st it is zero on $|z|=2$ too since $|f|=R$ there so $\log (2R)-c\log 4=0$ gives that $c$; this means $\log (2|f|)-c\log (2|z|)=0$  in the annulus so $f$ is essentially $az^c$, so $c$ is integral and then $c=1$ by injectivity on the boundary, so $f$ hence $h$ is analytic isomorphism

Comment: wow, I think I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: Another approach: Let $\Gamma$ be a standard cycle on boundary that has winding number 0 for $z \not \in A$ (Artin's Criterion).  $h$ is uniformly continuous on $\partial A$ so apply dog-on-a-leash lemma to cycle $\Sigma$ that is a close enough approximations of $\Gamma$.. i.e. you can apply the Argument Principle on this approximation to see every element in the image has valency 1.  i.e. you can reason for $w\in f(A)$ that $1=n\big(f\circ \Gamma, w\big)=n\big(f\circ \Sigma, w\big)=\sum_{z,f(z)=w} v_f(z)\cdot n\big(\Sigma,z\big)$.  (Technical nit I have $A$ a Domain and $\overline A$ compact)

Comment: @user8675309 is $\Gamma$ the union of the two boundary circles of $A$ connected by a little segment which is run over twice in opposite direction? I'm trying to figure out the details of your application of AP. $\Sigma$ is then an approximation of such path but inside $A$ so the function is holomorphic on it right?

Comment: @user8675309 modulo some details, I think I see your argument. I wonder why I thought that AP was not applicable here :/

Comment: @Conrad sorry for the follow up question, it seems to me that your reasoning actually only uses the fact that my function is injective on $1$ boundary component, not necessarily both. Because you used injectivity to find $c$ but that can be tested on just one of the two boundary components right?

Comment: Yea -- I ran over a character limit for my comment so I stomped on a few details but with a small amount of cleanup the above should prove that $h$ is injective on the interior of $A$.  And open mapping theorem makes it clear that this implies $h$ is injective on $\overline A$. Let me know if you want me to fully write this up to flush out residual details.

Comment: uses that in the general case since one needs that the image of the boundary curves to be (disjoint) Jordan curves so need injectivity on both circles; then one can apply Riemann mapping theorem extension for domains that are $1$ connected and get a biholomorphic map from the image onto an annulus; if you know the image is an annulus and boundary goes to boundary, indeed you need one injectivity only since same proof shows that any such map is a power of $z$ essentially (up tp biholomorphism)

Comment: any holomorphic surjective map from one annulus to another, continuous on the boundary and sending boundary circle to circle is essentially a power and the two annulus must satisfy a ratio relation (in other words from $ 1 \le |z| \le 2$ you can go with a map as above only onto $1 \le |z| \le 2^n,  2^{-n} \le |z| \le 1, n \ge 1$ so there is a strong rigidity); fairly sure I gave a complete proof here on MSE sometime ago

Comment: @user8675309 I you want I won't say no :) I just need to understand your last sentence "OMT makes it clear that this implies $h$ is injective on $\bar{A}$. I thought it was AP. Sorry, pretty rusty with complex analysis

Comment: Yes we can use the AP again. With $g(z):=h(z)-w$ and $g^*(z):=h(z)-w^*$ (to be used later), for $w,w^*\in h(A)$ the issue is that $n\big(g\circ \Gamma,0\big)$ isn't defined if the cycle $\Gamma$ takes the value $0$ under the image of $g$. So suppose there is a $w'\in \text{int}A$ and and $z'\in \partial A$ where $h(w') = h(z')$... OMT (+ JCT) implies a point $w^*$ in the interior of $A$ such that $0=n\big(g^*\circ \Gamma,0\big)=n\big(g^*\circ \Sigma,0\big)$ for arbitrary close enough $\Sigma$ and this contradicts the AP. Conclude $h\big(\partial A\big)\cap h\big(\text{int}A\big)=\big\{\big\}$.

Comment: sorry the ending should read "... a point $w^* =h(z^*)$ for some $z^* \in \text{int} A$ such that..."